# How to create Filter for custom field in Sale Order Grid magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, order-grid

This is my grid sale order grid have custom field Ready To Ship

[image]

This is my error

[image: ma]

Because Ready ship not in database. I just check condition to return Yes/No
[image]

**Now, how can filter custom field Ready To Ship**

Comment: how you created custom filed